# Too many processes?

Tags: vmware-fusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does VMWare Fusion negatively affect system performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/11735/does-vmware-fusion-negatively-affect-system-performance)

VMware Fusion v3.0.1

One vm for Windows XP, converted and recently expanded the disk size.

Mac OS X 10.5.8, 2 x 3 GHz dual-core intel xeon machine.

Immediately after booting, and before VMware Fusion is launched, the Activity Monitor shows eight processes associated with "vm". What caught my eye is the duplicates: netifup and dhcpd.

I noticed this while trying to re-establish network connectivity after the upgrade to 3.0.1. I am not sure when the network connection was clobbered, so I cannot say it happend during the upgrade.

Is eight processes typcial? I expect about six, as listed in other notes and documents on the web site.

Could this be related to the failure to connect to the network?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for superuser.com really, please take a look at our FAQ.

There's a question [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/11735/does-vmware-fusion-negatively-affect-system-performance) on SU that may be of help.

Oh and if you have =>4GB of memory I'd suggest you run Fusion 3 on 10.6 - it's a very 64-bit aware app.